Improve Linq2Db result mapper performance
Is there a way to improve the performance of the ORM mapper of Linq2Db using the FirebirdDataProvider. I retrieve 1831 records from a table having 39 columns (all INTEGER, DECIMAL(13,5) and 2x VARCHAR(100)). The longest varchar is 37 chars. Approximately 60% of all the values are null. I tried to log what takes so much time:
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
this.db.OnTraceConnection = (traceInfo) =>
{
    switch (traceInfo.TraceInfoStep)
    {
        case TraceInfoStep.BeforeExecute:
            sw.Start();
            break;
        case TraceInfoStep.AfterExecute:
            Console.WriteLine($"DB Request Time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            sw.Restart();
            break;
        case TraceInfoStep.Completed:
            Console.WriteLine($"Mapping Time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            break;
    }
};

Here is the result:
DB Request Time: 49 ms
Mapping Time: 1805 ms

DB Request Time: 43 ms
Mapping Time: 1870 ms

DB Request Time: 47 ms
Mapping Time: 1653 ms

DB Request Time: 40 ms
Mapping Time: 1820 ms

PC specs:

i7-13700K
64GB 4000MHz

Network should also not be the bottleneck. The last check I did resulted in 898.4 Mbit/s
I tried to use compiled queries but this did not improve the query at all:
DB Request Time: 45 ms
Mapping Time: 1953 ms

DB Request Time: 47 ms
Mapping Time: 1804 ms

DB Request Time: 48 ms
Mapping Time: 1832 ms

DB Request Time: 41 ms
Mapping Time: 1881 ms


Maybe the comments on this question might be of help. However, I've no idea if or how you can configure the fetch size when using Linq2Db.

You can override DataConnection.ExecuteReaderAsync, get the IDbCommand and if it's an FbCommand you can set FbCommand.FetchSize. I printed it first and by default it was 200. I increased it to 1000, but there was not improvement
